# How hard is disabling nuke by making it go fizzle with neutron radiation?

Tags: neutrons, nuclear-engineering

Suppose we would turn on nuclear reactor without shielding next to missile silo. Would it be able to protect silo by making incoming warhead fizzle out at reasonable distance?

--

Looks like it is impossible for modern warheads

> Boosted_fission_weapon Since implosion weapons can be designed that will achieve yields in this range even if neutrons are present at the moment of criticality, fusion boosting allows the manufacture of efficient weapons that are immune to predetonation.

Comment: You should read B. Cameron Reed's paper in the American Journal of Physics (aapt.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1119/1.3367757) to get a better handle on predetonation.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume for a moment that Vashu is not being ironic. If he is, I will delete this.

@vashu's good news isn't so very good. To make his idea work you would need to *aim* the neutrons at the target and there's no way to do that. It also means that every missile silo would need its own (big!!!) reactor built right next door to generate the neutron burst, which would enormously increase the cost.

If we consider fissioning U-235 to make fast neutrons the heat generated is enormous, which was why the Hanford facility was built right next to the Columbia River, which furnished a huge source of cold water to keep their neutron source (the fast breeder reactor) from promptly melting down.

To put the neutron burst close enough to the incoming warhead to fizzle it on its way in, you'd best just explode a hydrogen bomb in front of it before it goes off. This has the disadvantage of destroying the warhead's target for it, and thus is *impractical*.

Comment: I would say the same just several days ago, but then I did calculation and to my surprise the idea looked feasible. I am would bet there is error somewhere but I thin it is nontrivial enough to be interesting to others.

Answer (score -1):

Nuke would predetonate if it's core is exposed to at least 10^6 neutrons per second - about 10^8 m^2/s.

And in order to destroy hardened silo it must detonate pretty close to it - for half megaton weapon and 2,000 psi hardening that would be about 300 m - that corresponds to sphere with 10^6 m^2 of surface.

Warhead would cross that distance in about 0.1 second.

So we can neutralize incoming warhead with neutron impulse with about 10^13 (add 1-2 orders of magnitude to account for absorption in the air and warhead shielding) - 10^15 neutrons in 0.1 second.

That is corresponds to decay of 10^-9 mole, 10^-7 g, only about 10^4 J of heat - so we can hope to run impulse reactor many times.

So 1 MW reactor would generate about 10^17 neutrons, 10^11 neutrons/m2 at 300 meters - we have at least 3 orders of magnitude to go through shielding (4-6 orders if we run it really hard).

I checked Effects of Nuclear Weapons by Glasstone - it says that 300 m of air would half the neutron flux and warhead protection to kesse neutron flux 10 times would weight about 1 t/m2 - so instead of 10 warheads missile would have to take 1 at best.

So it looks very promising, and good news - it is way easier to protect military targets, so it would strengthen deterrence. But for some reason I never heard about projects like this...